# Pointer-stashing generics via `mem::transmute()`

Tags: pointers, rust, ffi

I'm attempting to write Rust bindings for a C collection library (Judy Arrays<sup>1</sup>) which only provides itself room to store a pointer-width value.  My company has a fair amount of existing code which uses this space to directly store non-pointer values such as pointer-width integers and small structs.  I'd like my Rust bindings to allow type-safe access to such collections using generics, but am having trouble getting the pointer-stashing semantics working correctly.

The `mem::transmute()` function seems like one potential tool for implementing the desired behavior, but attempting to use it on an instance of a parameterized type yield a confusing-to-me compilation error.

Example code:

```
pub struct Example<T> {
    v: usize,
    t: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Example<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Example<T> {
        Example { v: 0, t: PhantomData }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, val: T) {
        unsafe {
            self.v = mem::transmute(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Resulting error:

```
src/lib.rs:95:22: 95:36 error: cannot transmute to or from a type that contains type parameters in its interior [E0139]
src/lib.rs:95             self.v = mem::transmute(val);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Does this mean a type consisting only of a parameter "contains type parameters in its interior" and thus `transmute()` just won't work here? Any suggestions of the right way to do this?

([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330519/compile-time-generic-type-size-check), attempting to achieve the same result, but not necessarily via `mem::transmute()`.)

---

<sub>1: I'm aware of the existing `rust-judy` project, but it doesn't support the pointer-stashing I want, and I'm writing these new bindings largely as a learning exercise anyway.</sub>

Comment: An interesting question! It's almost like you want the ability to write `where sizeof(T) == sizeof(usize)`.

Comment: @Shepmaster: This would be tricky, because the link between the `where` clause and `transmute` would be slightly difficult to establish (especially if more general constraints can be used, like with `<=` and `>=`). On the other hand, it reminded me of: [RFC: Coercible and HasPrefix for Zero Cost Conversions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/270); the constraint could be enforceable for a `Transmutable<X> where mem::size_of::<X>() == mem::size_of::<Self>()` and then `transmute` from `T` to `usize` would require `T: Transmutable<usize>` => perfectly decidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of transmuting `T` to `usize` directly, you can transmute a `&T` to `&usize`:

```
pub fn insert(&mut self, val: T) {
    unsafe {
        let usize_ref: &usize = mem::transmute(&val);
        self.v = *usize_ref;
    }
}
```

Beware that this may read from an invalid memory location if the size of `T` is smaller than the size of `usize` or if the alignment requirements differ. This could cause a segfault. You can add an assertion to prevent this:

```
assert_eq!(mem::size_of::<T>(), mem::size_of::<usize>());
assert!(mem::align_of::<usize>() <= mem::align_of::<T>());
```

Comment: My goal is to have compile-time enforcement of size-compatibility, as `transmute()` does on bare values.  Transmuting references and adding run-time checks defeats the purpose.

Comment: Now that I have more Rust experience, I agree this is the way to go for now.  Assertions in construction methods can ensure the code is safe; the size-compatibility just can't be verified at compile-time.

Comment: Reading this again after your comment, I believe you also need to verify the alignment requirements of the types. I updated the answer accordingly.