# Compile-time generic type size check

Tags: pointers, rust, ffi

I'm attempting to write Rust bindings for a C collection library (Judy Arrays [1]) which only provides itself room to store a pointer-width value. My company has a fair amount of existing code which uses this space to directly store non-pointer values such as pointer-width integers and small structs. I'd like my Rust bindings to allow type-safe access to such collections using generics, but am having trouble getting the pointer-stashing semantics working correctly.

I have a basic interface working using `std::mem::transmute_copy()` to store the value, but that function explicitly does nothing to ensure the source and destination types are the same size.  I'm able to verify that collection type parameter is of a compatible size at run-time via an assertion, but I'd really like the check to somehow be at compile-time.

Example code:

```
pub struct Example<T> {
    v: usize,
    t: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Example<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Example<T> {
        assert!(mem::size_of::<usize>() == mem::size_of::<T>());
        Example { v: 0, t: PhantomData }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, val: T) {
        unsafe {
            self.v = mem::transmute_copy(&val);
            mem::forget(val);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, or is this run-time check the best Rust 1.0 supports?

([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328366/pointer-stashing-generics-via-memtransmute), explaining why I'm not using `mem::transmute()`.)

[1] I'm aware of the existing rust-judy project, but it doesn't support the pointer-stashing I want, and I'm writing these new bindings largely as a learning exercise anyway.

Comment: This doesn't work. It copies out the first word of `val` and stores it in v. Oh and if you want to store a pointer, store a pointer to something that actually lives -- such as a pointer to the `T` in a `Box<T>`.

Comment: "Copying out the first word of `val`" is what I want, as long as the type of `val` is exactly word-sized. The goal here is FFI interop with existing C code using data stored thus-wise.

Comment: I don't think rust can do a restriction on `T`'s size in general right now. However the assert is of course monomorphized and compiled at compile time, so at least there is no overhead.

Comment: Good point on the `assert!` getting resolved to a no-op or `panic!` at compile-time. If this sort of run-time check is in fact the best that Rust 1.0 can do, I'll accept that as an answer!

Comment: You could also write some `#[test]`s which contained those `assert!`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Rust 1.57, compile-time checks have been possible in safe code. As of this writing (Rust 1.67) they can be achieved using an intermediate compile-time constant outside the function. Here is how to do it:

```
pub struct Example<T> {
    pub v: usize,
    pub t: PhantomData<T>,
}

impl<T> Example<T> {
    const SIZE_OK: () = assert!(size_of::<T>() == size_of::<usize>());

    pub fn new() -> Example<T> {
        let _ = Self::SIZE_OK;
        Example {
            v: 0,
            t: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

pub struct Good(usize);
pub struct Bad(u8);

fn main() {
    let _e1 = Example::<Good>::new();  // compiles
    //let _e2 = Example::<Bad>::new(); // doesn't compile
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74e0177f4532ed1ebba9207be4341a8b)

Answer (score 9):

> **Note**: for Rust 1.57 and newer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75347371/2408867).

---

### Compile-time check?

> Is there a better way to do this, or is this run-time check the best Rust 1.0 supports?

In general, **there are some hacky solutions** to do some kind of compile time testing of arbitrary conditions. For example, there is [the `static_assertions` crate](https://crates.io/crates/static_assertions) which offers some useful macros (including one macro similar to C++'s `static_assert`). However, this is [hacky](https://nikolaivazquez.com/posts/programming/rust-static-assertions/) and **very limited**.

In your particular situation, I haven't found a way to perform the check at compile time. The root problem here is that **you can't use `mem::size_of` or `mem::transmute` on a generic type**. Related issues: [#43408](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43408) and [#47966](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47966). For this reason, the `static_assertions` crate doesn't work either.

If you think about it, this would also allow a kind of error very unfamiliar to Rust programmers: an error when instantiating a generic function with a specific type. This is well known to C++ programmers -- Rust's trait bounds are used to fix those often very bad and unhelpful error messages. In the Rust world, one would need to specify your requirement as trait bound: something like `where size_of::<T> == size_of::<usize>()`.

However, this is currently not possible. There once was a fairly famous ["const-dependent type system" RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1657) which would allow these kinds of bounds, but got rejected for now. Support for these kinds of features are slowly but steadily progressing. "Miri" was merged into the compiler some time ago, allowing much more powerful constant evaluation. This is an enabler for many things, including [the "Const Generics" RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2000-const-generics.md), which was actually merged. It is not yet implemented, but it is expected to land in 2018 or 2019.

Unfortunately, it still doesn't enable the kind of bound you need. Comparing two const expressions for equality, [was purposefully left out of the main RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2000-const-generics.md#equality-of-two-abstract-const-expressions) to be resolved in a future RFC.

So it is to be expected that a bound similar to `where size_of::<T> == size_of::<usize>()` will eventually be possible. But this shouldn't be expected in the near future!

---

### Workaround

In your situation, I would probably introduce an *unsafe* trait `AsBigAsUsize`. To implement it, you could write a macro `impl_as_big_as_usize` which performs a size check and implements the trait. Maybe something like this:

```
unsafe trait AsBigAsUsize: Sized {
    const _DUMMY: [(); 0];
}

macro_rules! impl_as_big_as_usize {
    ($type:ty) => {
        unsafe impl AsBigAsUsize for $type {
            const _DUMMY: [(); 0] = 
                [(); (mem::size_of::<$type>() == mem::size_of::<usize>()) as usize];
            // We should probably also check the alignment!
        }
    }
}
```

This uses basically the same trickery as `static_assertions` is using. This works, because we never use `size_of` on a generic type, but only on concrete types of the macro invocation.

So... this is obviously far from perfect. The user of your library has to invoke `impl_as_big_as_usize` once for every type they want to use in your data structure. But at least it's safe: as long as programmers only use the macro to impl the trait, the trait is in fact only implemented for types that have the same size as `usize`. Also, the error "trait bound `AsBigAsUsize` is not satisfied" is very understandable.

---

### What about the run-time check?

As bluss said in the comments, in your `assert!` code, there is **no *run-time check***, because the optimizer constant-folds the check. Let's test that statement with this code:

```
#![feature(asm)]

fn main() {
    foo(3u64);
    foo(true);
}

#[inline(never)]
fn foo<T>(t: T) {
    use std::mem::size_of;

    unsafe { asm!("" : : "r"(&t)) }; // black box
    assert!(size_of::<usize>() == size_of::<T>());
    unsafe { asm!("" : : "r"(&t)) }; // black box
}
```

The crazy `asm!()` expressions serve two purposes:

- “hiding” `t` from LLVM, such that LLVM can't perform optimizations we don't want (like removing the whole function)
- marking specific spots in the resulting ASM code we'll be looking at

Compile it with a nightly compiler (in a 64 bit environment!):

```
rustc -O --emit=asm test.rs
```

As usual, the resulting assembly code is hard to read; here are the important spots (with some cleanup):

```
_ZN4test4main17he67e990f1745b02cE:  # main()
    subq    $40, %rsp
    callq   _ZN4test3foo17hc593d7aa7187abe3E
    callq   _ZN4test3foo17h40b6a7d0419c9482E
    ud2

_ZN4test3foo17h40b6a7d0419c9482E: # foo<bool>()
    subq    $40, %rsp
    movb    $1, 39(%rsp)
    leaq    39(%rsp), %rax
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    callq   _ZN3std9panicking11begin_panic17h0914615a412ba184E
    ud2

_ZN4test3foo17hc593d7aa7187abe3E: # foo<u64>()
    pushq   %rax
    movq    $3, (%rsp)
    leaq    (%rsp), %rax
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    #APP
    #NO_APP
    popq    %rax
    retq
```

The `#APP`-`#NO_APP` pair *is* our `asm!()` expression.

- The `foo<bool>` case: you can see that our first `asm!()` instruction is compiled, then an unconditioned call to `panic!()` is made and afterwards comes nothing (`ud2` just says “the program can never reach this spot, `panic!()` diverges”).
- The `foo<u64>` case: you can see both `#APP`-`#NO_APP` pairs (both `asm!()` expressions) without anything in between.

---

So yes: the compiler **removes the check completely**.

It would be way better if the compiler would just refuse to compile the code. But this way we *at least* know, that there's no run-time overhead.

Comment: *If you think about it, this would also allow a kind of error very unfamiliar to Rust programmers* - apparently this kind of thing is now, some years later, [possible after all](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=505d2d7da0c5511c5012b9f7863ae8d1), as evaluating a constant can fail.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the accepted answer, you *can* check at compile-time!

The trick is to insert, when compiling with optimizations, a call to an undefined C function in the dead-code path.  You will get a linker error if your assertion would fail.

Comment: While this answer may or may not be true, in its current form it's so broad and lacking an example that it's hard to tell, which also means that it would be hard for someone to make actual use of this suggestion.