# check pointer size at compile time

Tags: rust

I found similar question [Compile-time generic type size check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330519/compile-time-generic-type-size-check), but it not received any answer.

The problem is in cooperation with other programming language via FFI + unsafe,
I want to be sure that `mem::size_of::<*mut T>()` have suitable size.
I found such `static_assert` macro in Internet:

```
macro_rules! static_assert {
    (type $t:ty; ) => (
        type __StaticAssert = $t;
    );

    (type $t:ty; $e:expr $(, $ee:expr)*) => (
        static_assert!(type ($t, [i8; 0 - ((false == ($e)) as usize)]); $($ee),*);
    );

    ($e:expr $(, $ee:expr)*) => (
        static_assert!(type [i8; 0 - ((false == ($e)) as usize)]; $($ee),*);
    );
}

static_assert!(2 == 2);
```

it works, but if I use `mem::size_of::<*const f64>()` inside macro all fails,
because of: `calls in constants are limited to struct and enum constructors`,
any idea how to calculate `size_of`  `*const f64` at compile time?

Comment: opening a duplicate is not the way to go if another question did not receive an answer, if you want to increase the visibility of the other question, consider adding a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to it

Comment: It does not look a complete duplicate to me, could you expand how this question is different from [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330519/compile-time-generic-type-size-check) you linked?

Comment: `mem::size_of` is not yet evaluable at compile time. Wait a year and the story might change (but maybe not, who knows?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pointers there is a configuration flag that you can check. You could do this to force a compile-time error:

```
#[cfg(not(target_pointer_width = "64"))]
compile_error!("Your pointers are too small. Please try again with a more expensive computer.");
```

In general there is the "transmute trick": to assert the size of something at compile-time, transmute it to something which is known to have the correct size in a dead function. For instance:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
fn _assert_pointers_are_64bits() {
    unsafe {
        ::std::mem::transmute::<*const f64, [u8; 8]>(panic!());
    }
}
```

These tricks will have to do until `size_of` is made into a const fn.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what type mean exclamation mark here ` -> !` ?

Comment: It means it is a [diverging function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#diverging-functions).

Comment: For the record, I've removed the `-> !` that @user1034749 asked about, due to [a compiler bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35849).

Comment: @durka42 for the note I create this bug report :)