# How to assert size of `usize` to drop support for incompatible platforms?

Tags: rust, size, platform, static-assert, compiler-directives

#### Problem

I've just caught my self writing **dynamic assertion** that depends on **a constant** `usize::MAX`.
I wrote:

```
  u128::try_from(letters.len())
     .expect("No suppor for platform with `max pointer value` >= 2**128.")
```

where `letters.len()` is an instance of `usize`.

Instead, I'd like my code to fail to compile on so rare (if existing) platforms with "pointers size >= 2**128".

#### I already know/read:

I've read  [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39023044/check-pointer-size-at-compile-time)  (suggested by community).
It shows methods to assert concrete size of pointer.
eg. `#[cfg(not(target_pointer_width = "64"))]`
I want my code to be very flexible. It's enough for `usize::MAX<=u128::MAX && usize::MIN>=u128::MIN` to be `true`.

#### Small reflection (maybe solution)

After some thinking, I concoct a solution that **works quite good**, both in my head & on the currently tested **Debian** with **x64** architecture and **Rust 1.60**.
Code: `const _:()= assert!(usize::BITS<=u128::BITS);`
Do you know any cleaner & edge-case-proof resolution?

Comment: This is a _direct_ duplicate, but for more general questions about static assertions in Rust see (related, but not exactly) [Compile-time generic type size check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30330519/7884305); Wow, there aren't (well, I couldn't find) any questions about general const assert in Rust!!

Comment: Your approach of `assert!()` is fine. As for the duplicate... I voted to re-open. There is no way to say GT/LT with `cfg`. However, not that, depending on your code, you may want a constant set of sizes, actually - will your code work with 48-bits sized pointers?

Answer (score 1):

`assert!()` is fine. [`assert!()` is only available in const contexts since Rust 1.57.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/12/02/Rust-1.57.0.html#panic-in-const-contexts), so if you need to support older versions you can use [the `static_assertions` crate](https://docs.rs/static_assertions/latest/static_assertions/macro.const_assert.html). The idea is to replace `assert!()` with the following constant expression:

```rust
const _: [(); 0 - (!(usize::BITS <= u128::BITS)) as usize] = [];
```

Now, if the expression evaluates to `true`, its negation evaluates to `false`, and `false as usize` is zero. So we're declaring a zero-length array and everything is fine.

However, if the expression evaluates to `false`, its negation is `true`, and `true as usize == 1`. `0usize - 1usize` overflows - and that is an error.

The downside is that it generates a pretty obscure error message:

```
error[E0080]: evaluation of constant value failed
 --> src/lib.rs:1:15
  |
1 | const _: [(); 0 - (!(usize::BITS > u128::BITS)) as usize] = [];
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ attempt to compute `0_usize - 1_usize`, which would overflow
```

(I swapped the condition so it will be `false`).

Comment: I don't understand what is an advantage of your solution over the one have shown:
    `const _:()= assert!(usize::BITS<=u128::BITS)`

Comment: @Sir That it works in Rust versions before 1.57.0. "so if you need to support older versions..."