# Why am I not allowed to transmute a value containing a trait's associated type?

Tags: rust

I have a type defined as follows (by another crate):

```
trait Bar {
    type Baz;
}

struct Foo<B: Bar, T> {
    baz: B::Baz,
    t: ::std::marker::PhantomData<T>
}
```

The type parameter `T` serves to encode some data at compile-time, and no instances of it will ever exist.

I would like to store a number of `Foo`s, all with the same `B`, but with different `T`s, in a `Vec`. Any time I am adding to or removing from this `Vec` I will know the proper `T` for the item in question by other means.

I know I could have a `Vec<Box<Any>>`, but do not want to incur the overhead of dynamic dispatch here.

I decided to make it a `Vec<Foo<B, ()>>`, and transmute to the proper type whenever necessary. However, to my surprise, a function like the following is not allowed:

```
unsafe fn change_t<B: Bar, T, U>(foo: Foo<B, T>) -> Foo<B, U> {
    ::std::mem::transmute(foo)
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
error[E0512]: transmute called with types of different sizes
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
13 |     ::std::mem::transmute(foo)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: source type: Foo<B, T> (size can vary because of <B as Bar>::Baz)
   = note: target type: Foo<B, U> (size can vary because of <B as Bar>::Baz)
```

I find this very confusing, as both types have the same `B`, so their `B::Baz`es must also be the same, and the type `T` should not affect the type's layout whatsoever. Why is this not allowed?

It's been brought it to my attention that this sort of `transmute` results in an error even when the type parameter `T` is not present at all!

```
trait Bar {
    type Baz;
}

struct Foo<B: Bar> {
    baz: B::Baz,
}

unsafe fn change_t<B: Bar>(foo: B::Baz) -> B::Baz {
    ::std::mem::transmute(foo)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0fb6d491bc15f9b5e191f6b8a93ef2d5&version=stable)

Bizarrely, it is not possible to translate even between `B::Baz` and `B::Baz`. Unless there is some extremely subtle reasoning that makes this unsafe, this seems very much like a compiler bug.

Comment: Whether this is a bug or a feature, you might want to open an issue about the error message, because it is quite confusing.

Comment: @mcarton Indeed, I think I will.

Comment: @Shepmaster Wow, that's even more bizzare.

Comment: @Shepmaster I added a note about it. I could just rewrite the whole question to concern that case, but I'm not sure if it would be bad etiquette. Also, it may potentially make the question harder to find for people who had my problem.

Comment: Proceeding on the assumption that this is a compiler bug, I've opened an issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49793.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for `transmute` size compatibility can't be verified at compile time for generic T values: so you have to use &T references:

```
unsafe fn change_t<B: Bar>(foo: &B::Baz) -> &B::Baz {
    ::std::mem::transmute(foo)
}
```

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328366/pointer-stashing-generics-via-memtransmute) contains some interesting details about `transmuting`.

Answer (score 0):

I released the [cluFullTransmute](https://crates.io/crates/cluFullTransmute) crate ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/clucompany/cluFullTransmute)) that solves your question, but it requires a nightly compiler. Give it a try.